# React-Formio problem while fetching data from external source

Tags: reactjs, formio

I am using `react-formio` version: `^4.2.5` for my project. I have problems with fetching data from external source.

I fetched data form an external resource (which requires API key for Authorization) using url resource in select component. After providing API key, I received 401 Unauthorized error. (I used the same API key to fetch the same data from the same resource on Postman and it works).

I tried to manually add the API key in `formiojs/components/select/Select.js` requestHeaders function and that error disappeared but "unable to load resources" returned. Dynamic select filtering example has the same error at this point.

Is there anyone can help me to fix this ?

Thank you.

P/s: Sorry for my bad English if it is hard to understand

Comment: It sounds more like a CORs/Ajax issue than a react formio issue. You should test loading the API data in the browser, without formio.

Comment: Hi @LessQuesar, I am using Access Control Allow Origin extension but it returns the same error. How about the problem with Unauthorized error ? Do you have any suggestion on that ?

Comment: Same answer this sounds like a cross domain issue - the server you are accessing does not give the correct response to the OPTION pre-flight request.